# Email works on Local Environment, but not Production Environment. Not getting any errors

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, debian

I have just moved my laravel 5.5 website to a server (digitalocean, debian9). For some reason emails wont get sent from my server and I'm not getting any errors.

.env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=MYDOMAIN
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-SECRET_KEY
MAIL_USERNAME=MYUSERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=MYPASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

config/mail.php:

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'MY_EMAIL'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'NAME'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

config/services.php:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

send mail controller:

```
public function sendMail( $id, Request $request )
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $data = [
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'bodyMessage' => $request->message,
        'image' => $request->image,
    ];

    Mail::to($user->email)
        ->send(new test($data));

    Session::flash('email', 'Message !');

    return back();
}
```

I looked through my UFW firewall and i couldn't see anything related to mail getting blocked.

My email Service (mailgun) doesn't output anything in the logs when i try to send a mail. So I guess its not even reaching them.

I have no idea what to do at this point. I don't even know where I should look for the problem, is it a server problem? laravel problem? firewall problem?...

Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: check port `587` is open or not? try with port `465` also.

Comment: If i do 'ufw status' I can see '465 ALLOW OUT Anywhere' and '587 ALLOW OUT Anywhere'. If i do 'netstat -tuplen' I dont get any ports, just protocols and ips, (i dont know what to look for)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check several things :

• Is your production .env correct ?

• Have you make a composer-install recently ?

• Are you sure the php versions of your dev and prod environnement are the same ? because Swift Mailer requires PHP 7.0 or higher (proc_* functions must be available).

Comment: yes everything is correct. Are there any other PHP libraries that needs to be installed?

Comment: maybe the mail() function but I'm not sure, have you try to use the mailgun api instead of the smtp version ?

Comment: Yes i tried using their API instead but no luck. Feels like i tried everything. Ended up using phpmailer instead which worked at first try.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it didn't work, feels like i tried everything. Ended up using PHPMailer instead, which worked fine.